# Listen() and select ()

Tags: c, sockets, unix, network-programming

I'm actually having troubles with a client-client application. Everything, in this question, is related to a Unix network programming environment.

This is my situation:

- I have a client (called `C1` from now on) that calls a `listen()` on a socket.
- C1 puts the `listenfd` socket associated with the previous `listen()` call in an appropriate `fd_set` variable and calls a `select()` on it.
- Once it receives a new incoming connection from another client (called `C2` from now on), the `select()` procs, the connection is successfully created with  `accept()` and the clients `C1-C2` start communicating.
- Let's call the `accept()` returned int `accfd` and the `connect()`returned int `connfd`.
- Once they are done, both `C1-C2` close the relative sockets with  `close(connfd)`,`close (accfd)`.

Once done, both clients have the opportunity whether to send/receive data again or not. If `C1` choose to restart its send/receive routine, the `fd_set` is zeroed (using the `FD_ZERO()` macro) and the `listenfd` is put again in the `fd_set` variable associated with the  previously called`select()`. The thing is, if `C2` tries to establish a new connection with `C1`, the second `connect()` doesn't make the`select()` proc in `C1`,even if the `connect()` call made by `C1` succeeds. This doesn't happen, if a third client (`C3`) tries to `connect()` to `C1`.

What I'm trying to understand, is *how can I close a connection with a client and open a new connection with the same client at a different time*.
Note that I don't want the clients to keep the firstly created connection after their send/receive routine is done. I want to create a new connection with both clients.

Here's the client code, note that I omitted obvious or useless parts of the code:

```
int nwrite,nread,servsock,listenfd,clsock[10],mastfd,maxfd,s=0,t=0,i=0,j=0;
int act,count=0;
for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    clsock[i]=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0); //clsock is an array of sockets. Each time C2 tries to connect to a generic C1 client, it uses the clsock[count] int. count is incremented everytime a connection is closed.
for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    if(setsockopt(clsock[i],SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,(char *)&opt2,sizeof(opt2))<0)
    {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(-1);
    }
listenfd=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0); //this is the listening socket 
if(setsockopt(listenfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,(char *)&opt,sizeof(opt))<0)
{
    perror("setsockopt");
    exit(-1);
}
if (listenfd<0)
{
    perror("Listenfd: ");
    exit(-1);
}

if (bind(listenfd,(struct sockaddr*)&cl2addr,sizeof(cl2addr))<0)
{
    perror("Binding: ");
    exit(-1);
 }
if (listen(listenfd,100)<0)
{
    perror("Listening: ");
    exit(-1);
}
do
{
    do
    {
        FD_ZERO(&readfd);
        FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO,&readfd);
        FD_SET(listenfd,&readfd); //the listenfd socket is added
        FD_SET(servsock,&readfd);
[... Maxfd and the elaps structure are set....] 
        act=select(maxfd,&readfd,NULL,NULL,&elaps); //maxfd is calculated in another piece of code. I'm sure it is right.
        system("reset");
            if (FD_ISSET(listenfd,&readfd)) //when the listen procs, the loop ends for C1.
            {
            [...exits from the first  do-while loop...]
        }
        if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO,&readfd)) //this is where c2 exits from the loop
        {
          s=1;
          do some things here.
        }
    [.....some useless code here .....]
    }
    while (s!=1); //this is the condition used by c1/c2 to exit the loop
if (t==1) //this is what C1 runs, having t=1.
    {
        if ((mastfd=accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *) &cl2addr,&cllen))<0) //C1 accepts a generic connection
        {
            perror("Accept: ");
            exit(-1);
        }
[....do some things...]
        if (close(mastfd)<0) //Once done, it closes the actually connected socket
            {
                perror("Error closing mastfd");
                _exit(-1);

            }
    }
else //this is what C2 runs
    {   
        claddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(ipbuff); // ipbuff is C1 port
        claddr.sin_port=htons(sprt); //sprt is C1 port
        if (connect(clsock[count],(struct sockaddr *) &claddr,sizeof(claddr))<0) //create a connection between C1 and C2
        {
            perror("Connect: ");
            printf("ERROR: %s",strerror(errno));
            exit(-1);   
        }
[....do some things...]
        if (close(clsock[count])<0)
        {
            perror("Error closing socket!");
            _exit(-1);
        }
count++; //increment count to be able to create a new connection and not to re-use the same socket in the clsock[count] array.
    }
if (menu==1)
    {           
        memset(&claddr,0,sizeof(claddr)); //this was when my brain was about to pop off
        fflush(stdin);
        fflush(stdout); 
        t=0;
        s=0;
        num_usr=0;
        system("reset");
        FD_ZERO(&readfd); //this is when my brain totally popped off
        FD_CLR(listenfd,&readfd);
        FD_CLR(servsock,&readfd);
        FD_CLR(STDIN_FILENO,&readfd);
        FD_SET(listenfd,&readfd);
        FD_SET(servsock,&readfd);
        FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO,&readfd);
    }
} while (menu==1)
```

Thank you all, if the question isn't well proposed or written, please let me know that. I'm sorry for my inexperience and for my English, I'm just getting started with network programming. Thank you so much, in advance, for your help.

Comment: Most likely seeing the proper parts of the code would help to understand the problem, or even a [mcve]

Comment: I always make the same mistakes, I try to format the code in the proper way, I end up failing. I try to describe my problem, I end up failing. I try to put some code in it, I end up failing. I'm actually having great thoughts about my life and what I'm doing here. Just kidding, I will provide some code. Thank you.

Comment: Be wary of [using `fflush(stdin)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin) — if you're on Unix, it's basically wrong.  Nested `do … while` loops are worrying.  The huge blocks of code in a single function are very worrying.  It is hard to see what's going on where — which makes it hard to work out what might be going wrong.  What does `system("reset")` do on your machine?  It jiggers the terminal into a known state on macOS.  You need to reduce your code so it is simpler, and compilable — the MCVE already requested.

Comment: I'm trying my best, I swear. I will shrink the code as possible. I'm sorry.

Comment: Why did you remove the listenfd from the fdset in the first place? Just leave it there. You should always be interested in new connections, not just when the old one has gone.

Comment: Trying to make it work, I thought maybe that it could have been a select issue. So I removed listenfd from the fdset at the end of the loop and re-added it at the beginning of the loop. That should not 'cause troubles. By the way, without removing the listenfd from the fd_set, the program still doesn't work. I am having serious thoughts about my programming skills. Please, tell me everything that's wrong in this code, I really appreciate it. Thank you so much, in advance.

Comment: It's impossible to help you if you don't add more code in your snippet. Because of the problem you are having, it is necessary to see what you do inside the loop that accept connections and what you do with the sockets. The problem you are describing is related to something you do during the lifecycle of the listening sockets.

Comment: I removed all the functions or blocks of code that deal with the sockets. Whenever you read ` do something here` etc., that means that the code in that piece is useless for debugging purposes (for example, it does something with variables, without influencing the connection etc). That's why I omitted some code. By the way, the problem has been solved as I wrote in my own answer. I don't know if you have or have not enough info to explain why that made it run. Thank you so much for your efforts, by the way. I appreciate all of it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any code calculating a new `maxfd` value when preparing `readfd` for `select()`.  When calling `select()`, `maxfd` must be the value of the highest descriptor + 1 of all the provided `fd_set`s. There is no code shown that calculates `maxfd` each time `readfd` is reset.  You need to do something like this:

```
FD_ZERO(&readfd);
FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &readfd);
maxfd = STDIN_FILENO;
FD_SET(listenfd, &readfd);
maxfd = max(listenfd, maxfd);
FD_SET(servsock, &readfd);
maxfd = max(servsock, maxfd);

act = select(maxfd+1, &readfd, NULL, NULL, &elaps);
```

Also keep in mind that on some systems, `select()` modifies the `timeval` structure to report the amount of time remaining after `select()` exits, so you should reset `elaps` every time you call `select()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As it is stated in the comments in my code, maxfd is calculated at each iteration of the do-while loop. The timeval structure is also reset at the beginning of each iteration. (forgot to write it.)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue removing the line at the end of the code 
 `memset(&claddr,0,sizeof(claddr));`
Even though it solved my problem, I don't really know why this wasn't making the code work. If someone could explain that, it would be great.